# Stripe integration - best approach for front end and back end

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I'd like to ask about best approach for integrating Stripe payment for FrontEnd and Backend.
As far as I understand from webpage https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder we should use following flow:

1. FrontEnd asks Backend for clientSecret to continue payment. That means that Backend doesn't have to know about credit card and other secured information, but can securely build request from payment and calculate amount to be paid.
2. Once Stripe payment is finished FrontEnd gets the result of payment and then can send paymentId to the
   Backend and Backed receives details from Stripe based on paymentId.

Is it the best and most secured way of payment? What should happend in case of issues with FrontEnd - payment is successfully processed, but because of some issue paymentId was not send to the Backend?

Comment: As long as you're following Stripe guides like the one at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment you're in good shape. There are many possible approaches based on what types of payments you're processing and many other factors.